# How do I know what the x-label and y-label in my histogram are in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to create a histogram. I am unable to read the histogram properly because it does not have x-labels and y-labels on it. How to add these on the following code?

```
compensation['Total_Pay_Dollars'].hist()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want the xlabel, ylabel  along the x/ y axis only or you want the values of histogram bars to be printed on them? The first option is simple though. An example  or similar chart to your desired output will be good....

Comment: It looks nothing like the column as it is in the millions, hence why I am having difficulty making sense of the graph. There is 120 ranks and the amount made is in the millions by these individuals.

Comment: Can you please post the datframe (compensation) you are trying to plot?

Comment: Answered. pls check and accept if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I would prefer a bar chart rather than histogram for segregation. If you chose histogram, I assume you have reason.
I created a sample data frame with with 50 rows of Total pay in the range of 50 million USD. You may replace this with df['Total Pay']. Also You may choose the X axis to be the employee name: df['Name']. If you turn that column to index it should auto plot using the below code.

The issue you are facing is because matplotlib turns the numbers shorter or scientific format.That why you see 1e7 towards the end of your axis. I used the line below(commented put beside) to get rid of that.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(0,53250000,50), columns = ['Total Pay'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y') # To display the total pay in actual numbers in plain format
plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.xlabel('\nEmployees\n', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('\nTotal Pay in USD\n', fontsize = 20)
plt.tick_params( labelsize = 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or simply add the below line to your code - you should be able to see the numbers (in case histogram is a must). Add the xlabel / ylabel as you need from above code.

```
df['Total Pay'].hist()
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #Add this line to see the numbers in plain format
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use API set_xlabel to set x-axis label and set_ylabel to set y-axis label. Can be something like the folllowing:

`emyhist = compensation['Total_Pay_Dollars'].hist()
 myhist.set_xlabel("my x-axis label", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)
 myhist.set_ylabel("my y-axis label", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)`

You can follow [this tutorial](https://mode.com/example-gallery/python_histogram/) for more customization.